# Maximum Area of the triangle ABC

Tags: trigonometry

If $a,b,c$ are sides of the triangle ABC where $0\le a\le 1$,$1\le b\le 2$ & $2\le c\le 3$. Then find the maximum area of the triangle ABC.

I am not able to solve it because of three terms and varying size of the sides. I am not able to achieve the optimum value.

Comment: If the sides a,b,c in order are taken as 1,2,$\sqrt5$ we get the answer 1, but is there any other method to solve ir

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of the values of $b,c$, increasing $a$ cannot reduce the area of the triangle (because it cannot reduce the angle $A$ opposite to side $a$, and the area is $\frac{1}{2}bc\sin A$). So for the maximum we must take $a=1$. Now the area cannot exceed $\frac{1}{2}ab$ and can only achieve that if the sides $a,b$ are perpendicular. So the maximum will be if $b=2$ provided that the resulting $c$ is within the required range, which it is ($c=\sqrt5$).